Converting images from grayscale to RGB confusion
When I view an image that I have “converted to grayscale” by reading it in with code it comes up as RGB.
But when I click on the image file in the directory it comes up as grayscale this is quite confusing is someone able to help?
`import os
import cv2
def convert_images_to_grayscale(input_dir, output_dir):
"""
Convert all images in the input directory to grayscale and save them in the output directory.
Args:
    input_dir (str): Path to the directory containing input images.
    output_dir (str): Path to the directory to save grayscale images.
"""
# Create output directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# List all files in the input directory
files = os.listdir(input_dir)

# Iterate over each file
for file in files:
    # Check if the file is an image (you can add more image extensions if needed)
    if file.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.gif', '.tif', '.tiff')):
        # Read the image
        img_path = os.path.join(input_dir, file)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        
        # Convert the image to grayscale
        gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        # Save the grayscale image
        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, file)
        cv2.imwrite(output_path, gray_img)
        print(f"Converted {file} to grayscale and saved as {output_path}")`

# Example usage: #input_directory = '/path/to/input/directory' #output_directory = '/path/to/output/directory' #convert_images_to_grayscale(input_directory, output_directory)
convert_images_to_grayscale('OCT/kermany2018/oct2017/OCT2017/test/DRUSEN', 'OCT/greytest/greydrusen')
When i view these images in the directory (double clicking the file in the jupyter environment) it shows up grayscale, when i read images in with the following:
img = mpimg.imread('OCT/greytest/greydrusen/DRUSEN-1193659-1.jpeg') imgplot = plt.imshow(img) plt.show()
it shows as rgb
